# nodejs new Error(message) and Object.keys()

Tags: node.js

```
const err = new Error('invalid');
err.code = 200;
console.log(Object.keys(err));
```

=>

```
[ 'code' ]
```

Why isn't `message`, or `stack` a key of `err`?

Isn't `Error` an ES6 Class?

What is the implementation of `err.getAllProperties()` so that it returns `code` as well as its 'hidden' properties like `message` and `stack`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Object.keys(err).forEach(function(key) {
  var val = err[key];
  console.log(val);
});
```

use

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(err).forEach(function (key) {
  var val = err[key];
  console.log(val);
});
```

Output:

```
This is stack info

This is an error message

200
```

More information on [Object.getOwnPropertyNames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames).

Comment: I may have worded my question really poorly. Your code is not what I am after.

Comment: @Alex I see what you mean now. You could try `getOwnPropertyNames` instead of `Object.keys` in order to return all properties.

Comment: thanks @gotnull, ```getOwnPropertyNames``` is what I was after.